# How can I repeat countdown timer daily and with multiple times per day?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a countdown timer for the next outgoing ship. The ship leaves multiple times per day and I want the counter to count down to the next outgoing time. When the last time has count down to 0 it should start over with the first time in the next morning.

There are 6 times per day.

Here's what I have so far but it seems like it's not repeating.

```js
(function () {
 var d1 = new Date;
 d1.setHours(6, 20, 0);
 var d2 = new Date;
 d2.setHours(9, 45, 0);
 var d3 = new Date;
 d3.setHours(11, 30, 0);
 var d4 = new Date;
 d4.setHours(15, 0, 0);
 var d5 = new Date;
 d5.setHours(15, 30, 0);
 var d6 = new Date;
 d6.setHours(20, 15, 0);


 function pad(num) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
 }

 function tick() {
  var now = new Date;
  if (now > d6 || now < 0 && now < d1) {
   var remain = ((d1 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Red";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else if (now > d1 && now < d2) {
   var remain = ((d2 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Green";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else if (now > d2 && now < d3) {
   var remain = ((d3 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Red";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else if (now > d3 && now < d4) {
   var remain = ((d4 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Green";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else if (now > d4 && now < d5) {
   var remain = ((d5 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Red";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  } else if (now > d5 && now < d6) {
   var remain = ((d6 - now) / 1000);
   var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
   var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
   var ss = pad(remain % 60);
   document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
   document.getElementById('time').style.color = "Red";
   setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
 }
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', tick);
})();
```

```html
<p>Next outgoing ship:&nbsp;<span id="time">&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Thankful for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create `d1`, `d2` once, when the script starts, for the current day. To make them repeat you have to recreate the dates whenever the day changes. To simplify that you could just move them into `tick()`. Then they will be recreated every second, most of the time the dates will be the same, but at midnight they'll change.

I'd write the whole thing as:

```
  const times = [
    [6, 20, "green"], [9, 45, "red"], [11, 30, "green"], [15, 0, "red"], [15, 30, "green"], [20, 15, "red"]
  ]

  const timer = document.getElementById('time');


  setInterval(function tick() {
     const now = new Date();
     const nextShip = times.find(it => it[0] > now.getHours() || it[0] == now.getHours() &&  it[1] >= now.getMinutes()) || times[0];

    let hours = nextShip[0] - now.getHours();
    let minutes = nextShip[1] - now.getMinutes();

    if(minutes < 0) { minutes += 60; hours -= 1 }
    if(hours < 0) { hours += 24; }

    const seconds = 60 - now.getSeconds();

    timer.innerHTML = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    timer.style.color = nextShip[2];

  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas! With the ".reverse()" the counter is counting down to 8.15pm with my current time (just past midnight here at this moment). If I remove the ".reverse()" it's counting down to the first time in the morning 6.20am. Why did you include it? I'll see what happens with the counter in the next day.

Comment: Jonas, a few more things. I had to remove the `&& it[1] >= now.getMinutes()` because that caused it to skip items in the array in some occasions. And the remaining time is not correct. I think it's the subtraction of the minutes that's causing the issue. If it calculates 20 - 50 minutes, it shows as -30 minutes instead  of subtracting one hour and set it to 30 minutes. I'm not sure how to calculate the time correctly.

Comment: Oh, right, did not think about that ... The edit should work now.

Comment: Jonas, I'm really thankful for your help! I've now a fully functional counter just the way I want it! However I had to add this too `if(hours < 0) { hours += 24 }` Maybe you can add that to your answer so we have everything organized?

Comment: Sure, glad to help :)